# Do Cardassians age faster than Bajorans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I am asking this as I think I have hit a snag in my watching of DS9.

Kira was born 2343 and joined the Shakaar resistance cell in 2356 
(Kira's birth date is an approximation as is her joining the resistance)

So by the time of the Kiessa Monastery massacre Kira is at least (12-14 years).

Legate Tekeny Ghemor is 19 years old, and is one of 400 Cardassian soldiers that participated in the massacre.

By the time of DS9 episode [Ties of Blood and Water](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ties_of_Blood_and_Water_(episode)) (5x19) Tekeny is dying and has come to DS9 to be with Kira. Why is there such a significant age difference between the two of them?

Kira looks like a woman in her thirties and Takeny looks like a man in his late years.

Hence my question.
**Do Cardassians age significantly faster than Bajorans?**

(Or is this one of those “oops” moments that nobody thought about when writing the episode?)

Comment: Dying ages a man, you know! :)

Comment: @Paulie_D whaa?? really? how can he look like late 60s and she like mid 30s if she was 13 and he 19 at the massacre.

Comment: Nana Visitor is 18 years younger than Laurence Pressman and I always have trouble guessing ages of scaled aliens, Plus, as I said, he's terminally ill...that takes a toll. Plus we don't know a lot about relative life spans. Interesting if there is something canon on *that*.

Comment: In-universe she is 13 (ish) and he is exactly 19 at the time of the massacre. so a 6-8 year difference shouldn't be that obvious. Also there is another episode where Kira plays his Cardassian daughter in the previous season. cant remember the name now.

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but what's he dying of?  If it's some kind of degenerative disease that would account for a lot of visible aging.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Yarim_Fel_Syndrome

Comment: Related - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65151/how-long-does-the-average-cardassian-live

Answer (score 3):

Your error here is in identifying Kira's age in relation to the destruction of the Kiessa monastery. All signs point to this massacre occurring sometime around the 2330s, around 12-15 years ***prior to*** Kira Nerys's birth.

This would make Ghemor approx 60 years of age at the time of his death, as compared to Major Kira who was 30 years old in 2373.

Comment: her father was killed in the massacre. it is specifically stated in the episode. if he is dead he cant make kira. so somebody messed something up here. I'm just curious to figure out what and how. or it might just be that cardassians age exsponentialy fast or some such weird thing. Or lets just say midiclorians and everything is solved.

Comment: @Cherebul - Her father was not killed in the massacre; http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Kira_Taban